# Any Ideas how to optimize my small Jquery Code for a menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 3 divs(#carta1,#carta2 and #carta3) that are hidden (display:none), each one with different information. When the user goes over a navigation bar the corresponding div is shown.
 It works fine but i think its to much code.. is there any way to make it simpler(for example to use only 1 function)?

thanks for the help!

here´s my Jquery code:

```
$("#frueh, #carta1").hover(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#carta1").stop().fadeIn();   
     }, 
        function(){
        $("#carta1").stop().fadeOut(750);
});



$("#sup, #carta2").hover(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#carta2").stop().fadeIn(); 
     }, 
        function(){
        $("#carta2").stop().fadeOut(500);
});


$("#sal, #carta3").hover(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#carta3").stop().fadeIn();   
     }, 
        function(){
        $("#carta3").stop().fadeOut(750);
});
```

and here´s the Html list:

```
<ul id="speise">
                <li><a id="frueh"  href="">Frühstück</a></li>
                <li><a id="sup"    href="">Suppen</a></li>
                <li><a id="sal"    href="">Salate</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You should try to avoid hover as it doesn't exist on touchscreen devices.

Comment: Where are `#carta1`,`#carta2` and `#carta3`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you have repeated code like that, it's usually a sign that you could put it into a function.

```
function registerHoverListener(triggerElementId, displayElementId, fadeoutTime) {
    var fadeIn = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(displayElementId).stop().fadeIn();
    };

    var fadeOut = function() {
        $(displayElementId).stop().fadeOut(fadeoutTime);
    };

    $(triggerElementId, displayElementId).hover(fadeIn, fadeOut);
});

registerHoverListener("#sup, #carta2", 500);
registerHoverListener("#sal, #carta3", 750);
registerHoverListener("#frueh, #carta1", 750);
```

You may be able to remove the `fadeoutTime` param if you only want it to be 750 in all the cases.  I didn't know if that 500 was a typo.

Comment: no worries :)  It always helps to have more eyes on a piece of code.

Answer (score 1):

thataustin's answer works well, another option would be to target down to your ul children, then grab the id from the event.
Something like:

```
$("#speise > li > a").hover(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert(e.target.id);
 });
```

Then you could make data tags or target children further to perform your desired actions, depending on where `#carta1`, `#carta2`, and `#carta3` are located.

Again, Austin's answer is easier to implement and easier to read, just food for thought.